# Image segmentation: how to isolate human body figure and a complex background?

Tags: image-processing, opencv, image-segmentation

I need do it without user intervention. The user upload a full body image and the server must change the background automatically. I think I will use the ImageMagik to change the background, but I have no idea how to remove the background. I am trying opencv+graphcut but i am not sure if is a solution. I know it's difficult but I have to find a feasible solution. Maybe you know some service to do this. You all can give any approach or suggestions that will make a real help to me. thanks in advance!

Comment: This is a hard problem, not the kind of thing you get a quick answer to on an internet site.

Comment: Hi, as Mark Ransom said (in the comments) it is a difficult problem and Mostly tell me what is your aim, do u wnat to segment humna dody boundries or you want to segment human body and its neighbourhood. As far as Graphcut is concerned it a semi automatic background subtraction technique. User has to provide two inputs by drwing small line segments on Foreground & also in background. iF U CAN UPLOAD some sample images, it will give good idea to us

Comment: Thanks for the answers!. I need cut the person like with magic scissors of gimp for instance and then put it into another image (a new background). Initially, the original background can be anything else... thats the problem.

Comment: Do everything you can to make the problem simpler before you attempt image processing. Can you require users to take pictures in front of a certain kind of background? Solving the general problem will not be feasible for one programmer in a reasonable amount of time unless you impose constraints on image capture.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with complex background then you should try GrabCut. It is interactive so you need additional information from the user.

Check also "[1.1 Previous approaches to interactive matting](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/67890/siggraph04-grabcut.pdf)" section.